# How to properly allow nil in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app my bands have many events. In the view of the bands it can show what events they have. My problem is if a new band is created it will throw an error in the view because it does not have an event.

I was reading about allow_nil and I wanted to use it in my bands model but Im not sure how to implement it. The documentation on it is pretty dry and not really helpful

```
class Band < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events :allow_nil true
end
```

Im not sure if the above way to do it is correct.

Comment: `:events` is active record relation, why we need it be nil?

Answer (score 0):

#### Rails 5.x

I think you are looking for [`optional: true`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), but it has to be added in the `belongs_to` side of the association, like this:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :band, optional: true
end
```

#### Rails 4.x

Rails 4 allows `nil` by default on any association, you just need to remove any validation that needs `band_id` presence.

Comment: @dutchkillsg What version of rails are you running? Maybe you just need to check the `Event` model validations. Check updated answer.

Comment: im running 5.1. The issue im having after using optional is that Im using venues to locate event. (band and event have an "@" before them"                                                                         
                band = Band.find(params[:id])

  event_id = Venue.select(:event_id).find(params[:id])
  event = Event.find(params[:id])

Answer (score -1):

I suspect what you're asking for (ActiveRecord-level data validations on associated models) isn't actually your problem. Your original question is about `allow_nil` but you state that (with emphasis mine):

> In the view of the bands it can show what events they have. **My problem is if a new band is created it will throw an error in the view because it does not have an event.**

What you're probably doing is attempting to show a list of events by iterating over them using `.each`, but since the collection of events does not exist `.each` errors out. Instead, before you do:

```
<% events.each do |event| %> # or similar code that you're using 
   ...                       # to iterate over the collection
<% end %>
```

You should check that `events.present?`:

```
<% if band.events.present? %>
  <% band.events.each do |event| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  # show something else
<% end %>
```

---

For the sake of completeness though, `allow_nil` is used on specific fields of a model to skip other validations on that field if that field is nil. ([See the documentation here.])(http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil)

It doesn't work in the code you posted in your question since there isn't an `event_id` field on your `Band` model—since it's a one-to-many association from `Band` to `Events` (assuming you setup your database correctly).